# Rename PHP filename inside directory

Tags: php, file, file-rename

I want to change filename in directory `carbrands/alto/alto.php` .Instead of `alto.php` I want to change as `alto_new.php`. But if I try to change name as

```
rename($old_name,$file_name);
```

After using this the filename changed but its not replace inside directory `carbrands/alto` instead its replaced out of directory. How to fix this issue?

Comment: provide full path with filename for both parameters

Comment: show $old_name,$file_name variables value...

Comment: Include the full path in the new file name

Comment: set chmod 777 before rename...may be file permisssion issue.

Comment: rename('picture', 'img506.jpg'); // looks for 'picture' in (current directory)

Comment: use full path for files.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to mention the entire path.

```
$old_name = 'carbrands/alto/alto.php';
$file_name = 'carbrands/alto/alto_new.php';
rename($old_name,$file_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rename("carbrands/alto/alto.php", "carbrands/alto/alto_new.php");
```

try this

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score -1):

I missed full path for $filename.Now I used full path for old and filename Now its worked correcly.

```
$pagename="carbrands/alto/alto.php";
$filename="alto_new.php";
$arr = explode("/", $page_name, 2);
$first = $arr[0];
$second1 = explode("/", $arr[1], 2);
$second = $second1[0];
$third = $second1[1];
$directory="$first/$second/";
foreach(glob('*.php') as $path_to_file) {
    $file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
    $file_contents = str_replace($page_name,$file_name,$file_contents);
   file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
}
rename($directory.$third,$directory.$file_name);
```

Comment: `rename($old_name,$file_name);` is the only line of code you posted and other answers were downvoted because of your not including your full code from the get go. What you should have done was post your full code and told others under theirs answers that theirs did not work. There were also comments under your question but you also ignored them.